# Surround selection with html tag

Tags: html, eclipse

Is there any eclipse shortcut/trick/plugin/whatever that will allow me to select a section of text and surround it with an arbitrary html/xml tag when using the html editor.

Something like [this textmate video](http://screencast.com/t/pesxOgON)

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: not sure If my Eclipse setup is the same as yours, but...

I have the HTML Editor installed, and if I switch to the Java perspective, I can use `Edit -> Quick Fix` and then choose **`Surround with new element`** to get exactly the effect in your video. (On a Mac, the shortcut for this is **⌘1**).

Hope this is helpful.

In the C++ editor, you can try `Source -> Surround With... -> Configure Templates` to add the tag you want.

Comment: Surround With doesn't seem to be available for html editor. Besides I need to use random tags...

Comment: random as in "not from a predefined list of tags". Just look at the linked video and you'll get what I mean :)

Comment: You're right +1. shortcut is CTRL+1 and seems to do what I want. The only problem: it's also auto formatting the selection and that kinda sucks. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean 'auto formatting'? The file is just plaintext, there's no formatting applied.

Comment: In my case I'm editing some html files with the Html Editor from WTP. I like this most of the time because of autocomplete features. But when I select a section of html document (let's say some nested divs'n stuff) and apply surround with, the selection is autoformatted, and I don't always agree with that format :)

Comment: You mean auto __indented__? With tabs and such?

Comment: Yeah, and it's doing havoc with sections that have template tags (e.g groovy template tags)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8932/discussion-between-richard-inglis-and-bogdan)

Answer (score 3):

The following works and allows for entering random/arbitrary tags:

1. Select the desired text that you want wrap.
2. Go to 'Edit > Quick Fix' or press 'Ctrl + 1'.
3. In the new menu that appears select 'Surround with new element'

However there is an annoyance, please upvote [Bug 494169](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494169)

[image: Eclipse Surround Selection With HTML Tag]

Comment: well, actually reformats all current line if you select only one part of it.